# Having trouble with Tkinter using OOP

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have created a small application in tkinter before using just top down programming but I am starting another project, this time using OOP and classes. But I'm having a hard time getting started, I just need someone to point me in the right direction. I've already dabbled in OOP with PyGame but I'm having difficulty with tkinter. Heres my code, where i'm just trying to display a button to the screen:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as ttk
import sqlite3

class Button(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        tk.Button(root, text = "Hello", width = 25)

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.button = Button()
        
        self.button.pack(side="bottom",fill="x")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: The `Button` class shouldn't rely on the global `root` variable. Also you should call `.pack`/`.grid`/`.place` inside the `Button` class on the `tk.Button`

Comment: @quamrana From reading the code it looks like the button isn't going to appear on the screen.

Comment: Well, we might know just from looking what the code actually does, but the OP might have a different definition of `having difficulty with tkinter`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you! When you say the Button class shouldn't rely on the root variable, what do you mean? Don't I have to pass the parent window as an argument to Button()? or do I pass it in as an argument to my button class. Where I would instantiate the button as such: self.button = Button(root)

Comment: @owwix your `MainApplication` class also shouldn't rely on the global variable `root`. Instead you should pass in `self` as in: `self.button = Button(self)`. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk # The `as tkk` isn't needed


# Here you might want to consider inheriting from `tk.Button` but it isn't going to change anything
class Button(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        # It's always a good idea to keep a reference to all of your widgets
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Hello", width=25)
        # You should call `.pack`/`.grid`/`.place` here:
        # Note it doesn't really matter which one you choose
        self.button.pack(fill="both")

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent # Technically this isn't needed because the line above sets `self.master` to parent

        self.button = Button(self) # Pass in self into the Button class
        self.button.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main_app = MainApplication(root)
    main_app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I passed in `self` when creating the `Button` object in `self.button = Button()` and I called `self.button.pack(...)` inside the `Button` class.

The whole point of OOP programming it to limit global variables and group similar objects in a single class definition. That is why both your `Button` and `MainApplication` classes shouldn't rely on `root`. Apart from that, your code is very nice :D

Comment: Thank you so much! I need some clarification though. You said to note that  "it doesn't really matter which one you choose." Do you mean it doesn't matter if I choose to pack or grid it or place it? Or that it doesn't matter whether I call .pack/.grid/.place in the Button class or MainApplication class? Because I noticed you packed the button in both classes, which is confusing me a little.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you used `pack`/`grid`/`place` inside the `Button` class on the `tk.Button`. I usually prefer using `pack` because it's easier to force widgets to expand. It's just a personal preference.

Comment: I see. Is there a reason you packed the button twice?

Comment: @owwix I packed it only once. Don't forget that in `self.button = Button(self)`, `self.button` is actually from the `Button` class. So it's a `tk.Frame` not a `tk.Button`. Look at the `class Button(tk.Frame)`. It forces the `Button` class to inherit from `tk.Frame`, therefore in the eyes of `tkinter`, it is a frame not a button.

Comment: @owwix Also I made a mistake an fixed my answer. I just noticed that I forgot to change `tk.Button(root, text="Hello", width=25)` => `tk.Button(self, text="Hello", width=25)`

Comment: So in the the Button class you are packing the Button into a frame and then in the MainApplication class you are packing the frame onto the root window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235766/discussion-between-owwix-and-thelizzard).

Comment: @owwix Exactly.